# How to detect the currently-logged in user's email address from Gmail inbox webpage (https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension that runs a content script in the user's Gmail inbox.

If the user is signed in to multiple gmail accounts (ex: a@gmail.com and b@gmail.com), I want to make sure my script runs only for the account he signed in to my extension with. So basically, if he signed in to my extension with a@gmail.com, the script should only run on the a@gmail.com gmail inbox webpage, and not the b@gmail.com gmail inbox webpage

Here's how I'm handling this right now: when my content script runs on the gmail.com webpage, it picks up the email address of the currently signed-in account by picking it up from the Gmail UI (the email address can be seen when you click on the user profile pic icon in the top-right.

However, this code breaks every time Gmail updates it's UI.

Is there a better way to get the email address of the currently signed-in user from the gmail inbox webpage, ideally one that's resistant to the Gmail UI changing?

Comment: That's a common problem in UI automation, and there's virtually no way you can counter it. If the GUI changes and your code relies on a specific area that doesn't exist anymore, it's pretty much dead. What you can do is rely instead on the help of the user, e.g. in your case, display a small prompt that asks something like "_Are you sure you want to execute extension Z on the current webpage ?_".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and the most reliable method I found was to get the email address from the tab title. So far it has been resistant to the Gmail UI changes.

```js
const title = document.querySelector('title').innerHTML;
const email = title.match(/(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/)[0];
```

The RegEx is from [emailregex.com](https://emailregex.com/)